# Android device throwing insmod: failed to load ./lime.ko: Required key not available

Tags: android, computer-forensics, lime

I am trying to create memory dump from android device using LiME with manual they provided

```
$ adb push lime.ko /sdcard/lime.ko
$ adb forward tcp:4444 tcp:4444
$ adb shell
$ su
# insmod /sdcard/lime.ko "path=tcp:4444 format=lime"
```

When I run the last command I get error `insmod: failed to load ./lime.ko: Required key not available`

My rooted Android 8.0.0 device uses limited number of programs whereas every solution I found was using Linux commands.

LiME version that I pushed to phone using `adb push` is 6.4.6. That was built in my laptop.

I suppose I should build LiME version that matches my Android's kernel(4.4.23).

Thank you all for responses!